# Struggling setting up a generic helper with Typescript in a React App

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

I am having real difficulty setting up a generic for a Text Input helper. This is where the Helper is used (I am getting an error on the `e` passed to `props.handleChange`)

```js
<TextInput
  hiddenLabel={true}
  name={`${id}-number`}
  labelText="Enter the number"
  inputClassName="number"
  inputValue={r.number}
  onChangeCallback={(e) => props.handleChange?.(r, e)} // GETTING AN ERROR ON the 'e' HERE
/>
```

e - error from the `onChangeCallback

```
Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>'.
  Type 'T' is missing the following properties from type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>': target, nativeEvent, currentTarget, bubbles, and 11 more.ts(2345)
```

And the helper itself:

```js
interface T {
  e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  r: Row
}

interface TextInputProps<T> {
  labelText: string
  hiddenLabel?: boolean 
  name: string
  inputClassName: string
  inputValue: string
  onChangeCallback: (arg: T) => void;
}

function TextInput(props: TextInputProps<T>) {
  return (
    <>
      <label 
        {...(props.hiddenLabel && {"className": "is-hidden"})}
        htmlFor={props.name}>
          {props.labelText}
      </label>
      <input
        className={props.inputClassName}
        name={props.name}
        type="text"
        id={props.name}
        value={props.inputValue}
        onChange={(e) => props.onChangeCallback?.(r, e)}
        placeholder="Enter the number"
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

This is a code example of it (sort of) - https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-shockley-mmehm

I have looked into the docs on generics in Typescript, but I have struggled to adapt the example to my use case with JSX - just need a few pointers in the right direction.

**Update - Fixed**
The onChangeCallback doesn't need to be generic, it can just return a change event. The helper now looks like this:

```
interface TextInputProps {
  labelText: string
  hiddenLabel?: boolean 
  name: string
  inputClassName: string
  inputValue: string
  onChangeCallback: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>
}

function TextInput(props: TextInputProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <label 
        {...(props.hiddenLabel && {"className": "is-hidden"})}
        htmlFor={props.name}>
          {props.labelText}
      </label>
      <input
        className={props.inputClassName}
        name={props.name}
        type="text"
        id={props.name}
        value={props.inputValue}
        onChange={(e) => props.onChangeCallback(e)}
        placeholder="Enter the number"
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

And the use of the helper:

```
<TextInput
  hiddenLabel={true}
  name={`${r.id}-number`}
  labelText="Number"
  inputClassName="name"
  inputValue={r.number}
  onChangeCallback={(e) => props.handleChange?.(r, e)}
/>
```

Comment: Please share reproducable example

Comment: I will make one up now @captain-yossarian

Comment: To make sure your question will not be downvoted, please always share reproducable example and your research effort

Comment: Will do, making the example now, and will explain what I have tried so far

Comment: @captain-yossarian - is that enough detail? I have put an example together.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should type your components:

```
import * as React from "react";

interface Row {
    id: string;
}

interface TextInputProps<T> {
    labelText: string;
    hiddenLabel?: boolean;
    name: string;
    inputClassName: string;
    value: string;
    onChangeCallback: (r: Row, arg: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, foo: T) => void;
}


function TextInput(props: TextInputProps<number>) {
    return (
        <>
            <input
                className="number"
                name="dfgsdgeg4-number"
                type="text"
                id="dfgsdgeg4"
                value={props.value}
                onChange={(e) => props.onChangeCallback({ id: '#1' }, e, 23)}
                placeholder="Enter the number"
            />
        </>
    );
}

export default function App() {
    const [r, setR] = React.useState({ id: "dfgsdgeg4", value: "" });

    const handleChange = (r: Row, e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setR({
            ...r,
            value: e.currentTarget.value
        });
    };

    return (
        React.createElement<TextInputProps<number>>(TextInput, {
            hiddenLabel: true,
            name: `${r.id}-number`,
            labelText: "Enter the number",
            inputClassName: "name",
            value: r.value,
            onChangeCallback: (row, e, arg) => handleChange(row, e) // arg infered as a number
        })
    )
}
```

To make possible use generics, I used react native syntax:`React.createElement` instead of `jsx`

You should use Optional chaining operator `?` only if value can be `undefined` or `null`.

Please see the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html)

Comment: Thanks @captain-yossarian, but the onChangeCallback needs to be passed `r` in the example I used above.

Comment: Thank you, but my initial need was for TextInput to be Generic, so the arguments it takes onChangeCallback to flexible. In this example, it can only take a Row. Does that make sense? Apologies if I am not explaining this well.

Comment: @LeMoi please try now. I have simplified your example a bit
To use generics, you should not use `jsx` but react native syntax.

Comment: Thanks @captain-yossain, but the onChangeCallback still has the hard coded Row arg into the helper?

Comment: @LeMoi it is just unclear for me, `T` generic parameter should represent the Row ?

Comment: as I understand it, you can pass types to a helper/reusable component to make it flexible. I am just struggling to adapt the example to my use case: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: Ahh it's sorted, will post above. Thanks so much for your help Captain

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear for me, do you still need generic or not :D ?

Comment: No, I thought I did, I thought the helper needed the Row in the arguments, but out doesn't. My apologies. What should I do? Delete this Question?

Comment: It is up to you. Better to leave it, maybe my answer will help anybody